# Row not added to table, but no error given

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails. I have a table called `TeamMemberships` that has 2 foreign keys: one to `Users` and one to `Teams`. I want to add a `TeamMembership` element to the `TeamMemberships` table from the `show.html.erb` page for `Teams` such that the `Team` foreign key is the `Team` that called the action and the `User` will be determined by a form. When I try to add the `TeamMembership`, the page redirects as expected, however, no table element is added and no error message is given. What could be causing this?
Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :instructors
  get 'static_pages/home'
  get 'static_pages/adminLanding'

  resources :audiences
  resources :comments
  resources :scores
  resources :projects
  resources :team_memberships
  resources :team_types
  resources :teams
  resources :users
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :teams do
      resources :team_memberships
    end
  end
  root 'static_pages#home'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Here is the link from the `teams/show.html.erb` page:

```
<%= link_to 'Add a student', new_team_team_membership_path(@team.id) %>
```

Here is the `new` method in the `TeamMemberships` controller:

```
  def new
    @team_membership = TeamMembership.new(team_id: params[:team_id])
    @users = User.all

  end
```

Here is the `team_memberships/new.html.erb` file for the form:

```
<h1>New Team Membership</h1>

<%= form_for @team_membership do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@users.collect{ |student| [student.first_name + ' ' +student.last_name, student.id]}) %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', team_memberships_path %>
```

Here is the `create` method of the `TeamMemberships` controller:

```
  def create
    @users = User.all
    @team_membership = TeamMembership.new(team_membership_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @team_membership.save
        format.html { redirect_to @team_membership, notice: 'Team membership was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @team_membership }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @team_membership.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should really just setup a method in your user model that concatenates the first and last name `def full_name; "#{first_name} #{last_name}"; end` so that you can use `collection_select` instead of that hacky mess.

Comment: Also you need to start troubleshooting by looking at the logs which will tell you what SQL query was executed.

Comment: You can use `save!` instead of `save` to raise an exception if it can't be saved for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You are not displaying errors in the view, add this to your `new.html.erb` and style it later according to your needs

```
<% if @team_membership.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @team_membership.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Try it once!

Answer (score 0):

You may check these

- team_membership_params should allow the columns you want to save
- TeamMembership model has the validations (otherwise raise errors at save) as you need